# How I get different unique number for every new payment request?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm developent payment plugin for PrestaShop, is there a way for get unique number for every payment request. Now I can do with cart ID, but this is unsecure, because consumer possible make request for product with price 20$, but pay 10$. Prestashop have functionality for different number for every request. I search solution for this without success, I sorry if this question is repeat.

Thanks for help! :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of generate an unique number. You can use cart ID as your said. You can concatenate it with datetime of payment. For example cart ID = 1 payment date 2017-01-01 00:12:00, result number will be 120170101001200.

Anyway, `ps_order_payment` table has a unique id after you insert on it.

Prestashop uses a function `generateReference` to generate a reference number. It calls to:

```
Tools::passwdGen(9, 'NUMERIC')
```

where the first argument is length and second type. It is unlikely but this function can generate duplicated results. That's why Prestashop check if it is unique with:

```
do {
       $reference = Order::generateReference()  
} while (Order::getByReference($reference)->count());
```

Good luck